# How to run multiple Django projects on Apache webserver (CentOS)?

Tags: django, apache, webserver, centos7

I have a Apache webserver and deployed multiple Django projects. So I want to know that what should do if somehow server shutdown or unable to connect with server. How to start or restart services to run my projects. For now, when I am closing my Kitty screen then projects are also not running. Please help me regarding how to run my django projects if I close Kitty session too.

I am attaching screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot to display issue]

Comment: Just curious what is Kitty ?

Comment: Kitty is free SSH or telnet client.

Comment: My suggestion is to start using docker, it's not so simple at the beginning but it is worth the effort: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application